# How do I wrap Linq2NHibernate's .Fetch and .ThenFetch inside my abstract repository?

Tags: repository, linq-to-nhibernate, eager-loading

I'm using a generic repository that exposes an `IQueryable<T>` like this:

```
public IQueryable<T> AllEntities
{
    get
    {
        return session.Query<T>();
    }
}
```

I can query like this:

```
var results =
    (from e in repository.AllEntities
     where e.SomeProperty == "some value"
     select e).ToList();
```

However, if `T` has a parent and grandparent entity and I want to load them eagerly, I have to do this:

```
var results =
    (from e in repository.AllEntities
     where e.SomeProperty == "some value"
     select e)
    .Fetch(x => x.Parent)
    .ThenFetch(x => x.Grandparent)
    .ToList();
```

This works, but `.Fetch` and `.ThenFetch` are both Linq2Nhibernate specific extension methods, which is causing two problems:

1. I have to include a `using NHibernate.Linq;` statement at the top of my file.  However, at the point that I'm doing this query, it should be implementation agnostic.
2. When I try to unit test this, the `.Fetch` and `.ThenFetch` methods fail when executed against the `IQueryable<T>` that my mock repository provides.

How can I wrap these inside of my `IRepository<T>` interface, or inside of some generic extension methods?

**Update:**

So far all I've come up with is to add this to my repository interface:

```
IQueryable<T> EagerLoadParent<U>(IQueryable<T> query, 
    Expression<Func<T, U>> parentExpression);
IQueryable<T> EagerLoadParent<U, V>(IQueryable<T> query,
    Expression<Func<T, U>> parentExpression, 
    Expression<Func<U, V>> grandparentExpression);
```

... and this to my NHibernate repository implementation:

```
public IQueryable<T> EagerLoadParent<U>(IQueryable<T> query,
    Expression<Func<T, U>> parentExpression)
{
    return query
        .Fetch(parentExpression);
}

public IQueryable<T> EagerLoadParent<U, V>(IQueryable<T> query,
    Expression<Func<T, U>> parentExpression, 
    Expression<Func<U, V>> grandparentExpression)
{
    return query
        .Fetch(parentExpression)
        .ThenFetch(grandparentExpression);
}
```

The consumer of this API now does this:

```
var query =
    (from e in repository.AllEntities
     where e.SomeProperty == "some value"
     select e);
var results = repository
    .EagerLoadParent(query, e => e.Parent, p => p.Grandparent)
    .ToList();
```

But this lacks the nice extension method syntax I'd prefer.  I'm looking for something closer to the `.Fetch` and `.ThenFetch` syntax.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some investigation I think I have a recipe: simply follow closely `NHibernate.Linq` implementation in order to have your own implementation and avoid an explicit NHibernate.Linq dependency in your client code. You just need to reproduce very closely
`NHibernate.Linq.EagerFetchingExtensionMethods` class.

It takes an interface: `IFetchRequest`, a class `FetchRequest` implementing `IFetchRequest` and a static class `EagerFetch` implementing extension methods. This is a sort of clone of `NHibernate.Linq.EagerFetchingExtensionMethods` class.

Just define:

```
public interface IFetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch> : IOrderedQueryable<TQueried> {}
```

which mimics `NHibernate.Linq.INhFetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch>`

then define an implementation:

```
public class FetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch> : IFetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch> {

    #region IEnumerable<TQueried> Members

    public IEnumerator<TQueried> GetEnumerator(){
        return NhFetchRequest.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return NhFetchRequest.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IQueryable Members

    public Type ElementType {
        get { return NhFetchRequest.ElementType; }
    }

    public System.Linq.Expressions.Expression Expression {
        get { return NhFetchRequest.Expression; }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider {
        get { return NhFetchRequest.Provider; }
    }

    #endregion

    public FetchRequest(INhFetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch> nhFetchRequest){
        NhFetchRequest = nhFetchRequest;
    }

    public INhFetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch> NhFetchRequest { get; private set; }
}
```

This one simply holds a nHibernate implementation and forwards every method to that member.

Finally:

```
public static class EagerFetch {
/*
    replacing methods from NHibernate.Linq.EagerFetchingExtensionMethods
    private static INhFetchRequest<TOriginating, TRelated> CreateFluentFetchRequest<TOriginating, TRelated>(MethodInfo currentFetchMethod, IQueryable<TOriginating> query, LambdaExpression relatedObjectSelector);
    public static INhFetchRequest<TOriginating, TRelated> Fetch<TOriginating, TRelated>(this IQueryable<TOriginating> query, Expression<Func<TOriginating, TRelated>> relatedObjectSelector);
    public static INhFetchRequest<TOriginating, TRelated> FetchMany<TOriginating, TRelated>(this IQueryable<TOriginating> query, Expression<Func<TOriginating, IEnumerable<TRelated>>> relatedObjectSelector);
    public static INhFetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated> ThenFetch<TQueried, TFetch, TRelated>(this INhFetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch> query, Expression<Func<TFetch, TRelated>> relatedObjectSelector);
    public static INhFetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated> ThenFetchMany<TQueried, TFetch, TRelated>(this INhFetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch> query, Expression<Func<TFetch, IEnumerable<TRelated>>> relatedObjectSelector);
*/  
    public static IFetchRequest<TOriginating, TRelated> Fetch<TOriginating, TRelated>(this IQueryable<TOriginating> query, Expression<Func<TOriginating, TRelated>> relatedObjectSelector){
        var fetch = EagerFetchingExtensionMethods.Fetch(query, relatedObjectSelector);
        return new FetchRequest<TOriginating, TRelated>(fetch);
    }

    public static IFetchRequest<TOriginating, TRelated> FetchMany<TOriginating, TRelated>(this IQueryable<TOriginating> query, Expression<Func<TOriginating, IEnumerable<TRelated>>> relatedObjectSelector){
        var fecth = EagerFetchingExtensionMethods.FetchMany(query, relatedObjectSelector);
        return new FetchRequest<TOriginating, TRelated>(fecth);
    }

    public static IFetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated> ThenFetch<TQueried, TFetch, TRelated>(this IFetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch> query, Expression<Func<TFetch, TRelated>> relatedObjectSelector){
        var impl = query as FetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch>;
        var fetch = EagerFetchingExtensionMethods.ThenFetch(impl.NhFetchRequest, relatedObjectSelector);
        return new FetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated>(fetch);
    }

    public static IFetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated> ThenFetchMany<TQueried, TFetch, TRelated>(this IFetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch> query, Expression<Func<TFetch, IEnumerable<TRelated>>> relatedObjectSelector){
        var impl = query as FetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch>;
        var fetch = EagerFetchingExtensionMethods.ThenFetchMany(impl.NhFetchRequest, relatedObjectSelector);
        return new FetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated>(fetch);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is really good, but now I do need to implement IFetchRequest that works with linq to objects?

Comment: @Chris - Would you please share what solution you found?

Comment: http://mycodinglife.blog.com/2013/06/10/fetch-good-boy-now-play-nice-with-my-unit-tests/

That works with Linq to Objects (with thanks to @KeithS).

Answer (score 1):

Building on guido's answer, here's one which disconnects all NHibernate dependencies from the repository interface. Quite a bit of boiler plate though and probably not a good technique if you want to make use of a lot of NHibernate specific functionality; then referencing the NHibernate.dll might be more appropriate.

First the interfaces:

```
public interface IFetchableQueryable<TQueried> : IQueryable<TQueried> {
        IFetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated> Fetch<TRelated>(Expression<Func<TQueried, TRelated>> relatedObjectSelector);

        IFetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated> FetchMany<TRelated>(Expression<Func<TQueried, IEnumerable<TRelated>>> relatedObjectSelector);
}

public interface IFetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch> : IOrderedQueryable<TQueried> {
        IFetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated> ThenFetch<TRelated>(Expression<Func<TFetch, TRelated>> relatedObjectSelector);

        IFetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated> ThenFetchMany<TRelated>(Expression<Func<TFetch, IEnumerable<TRelated>>> relatedObjectSelector);
}
```

And then the implementation:

```
    public class FetchableQueryable<TQueried> : IFetchableQueryable<TQueried> {
    public FetchableQueryable(IQueryable<TQueried> query) {
        this.Query = query;
    }

    public IQueryable<TQueried> Query { get; private set; }

    #region IEnumerable<TQueried> Members

    public IEnumerator<TQueried> GetEnumerator() {
        return this.Query.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return this.Query.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IQueryable Members

    public Type ElementType {
        get { return this.Query.ElementType; }
    }

    public Expression Expression {
        get { return this.Query.Expression; }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider {
        get { return this.Query.Provider; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IFetchableQueryable<TQueried> Members

    public IFetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated> Fetch<TRelated>(Expression<Func<TQueried, TRelated>> relatedObjectSelector) {
        return new FetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated>(this.Query.Fetch<TQueried, TRelated>(relatedObjectSelector));
    }

    public IFetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated> FetchMany<TRelated>(Expression<Func<TQueried, IEnumerable<TRelated>>> relatedObjectSelector) {
        return new FetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated>(this.Query.FetchMany<TQueried, TRelated>(relatedObjectSelector));
    }

    #endregion
}

public class FetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch> : IFetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch> {

    public FetchRequest(INhFetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch> nhFetchRequest) {
        NhFetchRequest = nhFetchRequest;
    }

    public INhFetchRequest<TQueried, TFetch> NhFetchRequest { get; private set; }

    #region IEnumerable<TQueried> Members

    public IEnumerator<TQueried> GetEnumerator() {
        return NhFetchRequest.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return NhFetchRequest.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IQueryable Members

    public Type ElementType {
        get { return NhFetchRequest.ElementType; }
    }

    public System.Linq.Expressions.Expression Expression {
        get { return NhFetchRequest.Expression; }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider {
        get { return NhFetchRequest.Provider; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IFetchRequest<TQueried,TFetch> Members

    public IFetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated> Fetch<TRelated>(Expression<Func<TQueried, TRelated>> relatedObjectSelector) {
        var fetch = EagerFetchingExtensionMethods.Fetch(this.NhFetchRequest, relatedObjectSelector);
        return new FetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated>(fetch);
    }

    public IFetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated> FetchMany<TRelated>(Expression<Func<TQueried, IEnumerable<TRelated>>> relatedObjectSelector) {
        var fecth = EagerFetchingExtensionMethods.FetchMany(this.NhFetchRequest, relatedObjectSelector);
        return new FetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated>(fecth);
    }

    public IFetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated> ThenFetch<TRelated>(Expression<Func<TFetch, TRelated>> relatedObjectSelector) {
        var fetch = EagerFetchingExtensionMethods.ThenFetch(this.NhFetchRequest, relatedObjectSelector);
        return new FetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated>(fetch);
    }

    public IFetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated> ThenFetchMany<TRelated>(Expression<Func<TFetch, IEnumerable<TRelated>>> relatedObjectSelector) {
        var fetch = EagerFetchingExtensionMethods.ThenFetchMany(this.NhFetchRequest, relatedObjectSelector);
        return new FetchRequest<TQueried, TRelated>(fetch);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've done to work around this is to create a `public virtual` function in my repository to `EagerlyFetch` my object.  Then, in my unit tests I use that Stub instead that passes through everything except for my `EagerlyFetch` method, which just returns a list.  Here is an example of what I've done:

```
public class PersistenceBroker
{
    private ISession _session;

    public IQueryable<T> Query<T>()
    {
        return Session.Query<T>();
    }
    .
    .
    .
}

public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    private PersistenceBroker _persistenceBroker;

    public List<Person> PeopeWhoLiveIn(string city)
    {
        var people = _persistenceBroker.Query<Person>()
            Where(x => x.City == city)l

        return EagerlyFetch(people);
    }

    public virtual List<Person> EagerlyFetch(IQueryable<Person> people)
    {
        return people.Fetch(x => x.Mom)
            .FetchMany(x => x.Children)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

And then in my tests, I simply provide a PersonRepositoryStub:

```
public class PersonRepositoryStub : PersonRepository
{
    public override List<Person> EagerlyFetch(IQueryable<Person> people)
    {
        return people.ToList();
    }
}
```

This would be an alternative to some of the above answers (which I have not tried), but this works for me.

Cheers,

Levi

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively wrap your test data IEnumerable in a stub that implements IFutureValue (NB this uses remotion http://relinq.codeplex.com/).

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using NHibernate;
using Remotion.Linq;

namespace SomeNameSpaceNearYou
{
    public class NhStubQueryable<TData> : QueryableBase<TData>, IEnumerable<TData>, IFutureValue<TData>
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<TData> _enumerable;

        public NhStubQueryable(IEnumerable<TData> enumerable)
            : base(new NhStubQueryProvider())
        {
            _enumerable = enumerable;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This constructor is called by Provider.CreateQuery().
        /// </summary>
        //public NhStubQueryable(NhStubQueryProvider<TData> provider, Expression expression)
        public NhStubQueryable(NhStubQueryProvider provider, Expression expression)
            : base(provider, expression)
        {
            if (provider == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("provider");
            }

            if (expression == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
            }

            if (!typeof(IQueryable<TData>).IsAssignableFrom(expression.Type))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("expression");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Enumerators
        IEnumerator<TData> IEnumerable<TData>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            if (_enumerable != null)
                return _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
            return (Provider.Execute<IEnumerable<TData>>(Expression)).GetEnumerator();
        }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            if (_enumerable != null)
                return _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
            return (Provider.Execute<IEnumerable<TData>>(Expression)).GetEnumerator();
        }
        public new IEnumerator<TData> GetEnumerator()
        {
            if (_enumerable != null)
                return _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
            return (Provider.Execute<IEnumerable<TData>>(Expression)).GetEnumerator();
        }


        #endregion
        public IEnumerable Enumerable { get { return _enumerable; } }

        public TData Value { get { return this.FirstOrDefault(); } }
    }

    public class NhStubFutureValue<TData> :  IFutureValue<TData>
    {
        public NhStubFutureValue(TData value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public TData Value { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

(I didn't write this, credit to a colleague far more skilled than myself)